# How to test if those 2 regression models are fundamentally equivalent?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I want to test/prove if two regressions are fundamentally the same thing.

But first, make this a reproducible example.

Create the levels for each factor variable

```
levels_a <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
levels_b <- c("B1", "B2", "B3")
levels_c <- c("C1", "C2")
```

Generate all possible combinations of factor levels

```
combinations <- expand.grid(levels_a, levels_b, levels_c)
```

Create a data frame with the factor variables and the dependent variable

```
data <- data.frame(
  a = factor(combinations$Var1),
  b = factor(combinations$Var2),
  c = factor(combinations$Var3),
  DepVar = sample(c(0, 1), size = nrow(combinations), replace = TRUE)
)
```

My original regression is

```
original <- glm(formula = DepVar ~ a*b*c , family = "binomial", 
            data = data)
summary(original)
```

A, B and C are all factors. A has four levels, b has three levels, and c has 2 levels.
Therefore, the "original" regression has an intercept and  3 terms from a, 2 terms from b, 1 term from c, then 6 (3*2) from a and b, and then, lastly, 11 terms from c (c= 1 times all before but itself).  In sum, these are 23 terms plus intercept. However, I want to use the `sjplot` for interactions, and this packet only allows one interaction. I want to plot the c- to the rest- interaction. So I thought maybe I could do it like this:

My second regression is

```
data$interaction_var <- interaction(data$a,  data$b)

test <- glm(formula = DepVar ~ interaction_var * c , family = "binomial", 
                             data = data)
summary(test)
```

While this interaction can be plotted with "sj", I want to find out if this regression always produces the same predicted values as the first regression, as this regression has different terms:

Again, it has an intercept, all 12 interactions (minus 1) from a and b, 1 from c, and again 11 (c=1 times everything so far but itself). So, it also has 23 components.

How can I show that they are identical in terms of predictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked

> How can I show that they are identical in terms of predictions?

If you just want a computational demonstration (rather than a mathematical proof),

```r
all.equal(predict(original), predict(test))
```

should do it ... (`all.equal()` automatically uses an "equivalent within numerical tolerances" test, rather than testing that the two predictions are identical up to the full floating-point precision).

You did say

> **always** produces the same predicted values

[emphasis added] (not "produces the same predicted values for the original data set"), but something pretty weird would have to be happening (or you'd have to pick a pathological data set) in order for the predictions to be identical on the training set but different for some other set of input.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the models will be identical and produce equal predicted values if they have same coefficients:

```
epsylon <- 10^-6 # set maximum allowed difference between coefficients
length(coefficients(original)) == length(coefficients(test)) &&
all(abs(coefficients(original) - coefficients(test)) < epsylon
)

[1] FALSE
```

And we can print different coefficients in a human readible form:

```
data.frame(coefficients(original), 
           coefficients(test))[
               abs(coefficients(original) - coefficients(test)) >= epsylon,
               ]

            coefficients.original. coefficients.test.
bB3                  -5.113214e+01       3.246735e-09
cC2                   1.014892e-07      -5.113214e+01
aA2:bB2               5.113214e+01       1.029394e-07
aA3:bB2              -4.707198e-09      -5.113214e+01
aA4:bB2              -1.057436e-07      -5.113214e+01
aA2:bB3               5.113214e+01       5.457133e-09
aA3:bB3               1.022643e+02       5.717070e-10
aA4:bB3               5.113214e+01      -1.227631e-09
bB3:cC2               5.113214e+01      -5.113214e+01
aA2:bB2:cC2          -5.113214e+01       1.227629e-09
aA3:bB2:cC2           5.113214e+01      -9.859460e-08
aA2:bB3:cC2          -1.022643e+02       1.227591e-09
aA3:bB3:cC2          -5.113214e+01      -2.211011e-06
aA4:bB3:cC2          -1.022643e+02      -5.113214e+01
```

Comment: Comparing the coefficients is relevant *only* when the variables are coded identically in both models.  Why not just compare the predictions to each other?

Comment: I think all the variables a, b, and c are the same, so they are also "coded identically". I use the same variables from the same dataset.